# How to remotely distribute an iOS app for testing without App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am building an iOS app and it is still in early stage for testing. My QA actually lives in another state and I can't install my app to his iOS device with physically connected option.

Is there a way that I can send the iOS app package to my QA and he can install it somehow in his physical device? Also, this app is still in early testing phase so I don't think we are ready for app store approval.

Comment: please search on ad hoc distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading [*Beta Testing iOS Apps*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html). What you're after is Ad Hoc Distribution, and there's been plenty written and asked about it. In addition to the tools that Apple provides, including TestFlight, you might also take a look at HockeyApp.